# Which language can I use to write a hook script in Git?

Tags: githooks

I would like to know the script languages that you can use inside hook script in Git.

I have been reading about how to use Git hooks but I have not seen anywhere the language that can be used, I have seen some examples that look they are written in Perl but I am not sure of that since I have never programmed in Perl.

Comment: You can use any language. I write mine in ruby.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any language, compiled or interpreted can be used (as long as the appropriate interpreter is available on the system).

The only requirement for hooks that run before events (e.g. `pre-commit`, `pre-rebase`, `pre-push` etc) and are allowed to block the event processing is to return the exit code `0` for success (let the operation continue) or a non-zero exit code to abort the operation.

The exit codes of the hooks that run after events (e.g. `post-checkout`, `post-commit` etc) do not matter; they cannot change anything, what had to be done has already been done before they were invoked.

Read the ["Customizing Git - Git Hooks"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) page from the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) for details.

Comment: Is there an example where a hook (say `pre-commit-msg`) is written in Javascript?